# I saw answers on excel to LaTex but do not want a latex table... Need to use LaTex in Excel to make .csv with math symbols, subs & supers, etc

Tags: csv, import, convert, excel

I am trying to make a csv file for flashcards that includes latex symbols, the file needs to be in csv format and I was editing it in excel to change the plain text such as d/dx f(x) or x^2 a_n etc to the actual mathematical symbols, subscripts, superscripts, etc but using the built in symbols in excel takes forever... is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, welcome. It's not clear what you want to achieve. `csv` is a plain text format; you can put LaTeX code as strings in it, but I don't think there's any software out there that will show them compiled to you.

Comment: As noted, `csv` is plain text. It has no mathematical meaning by itself. An interpreter program could convert the text into math symbols (that is what TeX does), but the result is no longer plain text, and therefore cannot be written as `csv` and would not be understood by Excel. If the purpose of the spreadsheet is to perform calculations based on the math expressions, I am afraid that this is either impossible or at least very difficult. But if the purpose is merely to display (for viewing) some equations, you could use TeX, convert result to images, and place images (not `csv`).

Comment: XY problem? Explain what is your *final* goal, not how you think you can reach it.  Probably there are ways to do what you want without Excel at all. Otherwise, probably there is some plugin or add-on to use LaTeX or MathJax in Excel, but I've never bothered to find out. Ask to Google.